No sound-card available in my Ubuntu 24.04
my English is not good. sorry.
I have made a mistake and the sound card driver is removed.

I don't know exactly with what command this happened, but maybe
because I installed x-ubuntu and deleted it again, it caused the
removal of the sound card.


Ubuntu version: 24.04.1 Lts |
Laptop: Asus g551vw |
Soundcard: Realtek

I tried different ways, such as uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa, but it didn't work.
I downloaded the realtek-linux-audiopack-4.06a.tar.bz2 package from the realtek website, but the following error occurs while installing:
Error: ./install: 102: alsaconf: not found

I also downloaded alsa-firmware-1.2.4.tar.bz2 and installed with make and make install but that didn't work either.
I also reset Pipewire but it didn't work.
myusername@myusername-G551VW:~$ aplay -i
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1342:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2721:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:834: audio open error: No such file or directory

myusername@myusername-G551VW:~$ alsamixer
ALSA lib confmisc.c:165:(snd_config_get_card) Cannot get card index for 0
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

My Output Device in Sound Setting is : Dummy Output | and Input device for my laptop microphone is : No Input Devices
Please help me. thank you

Please edit the question and add what you did, exact commands that makes you think you removed the sound card.

Have a look at /var/log/apt/history.log. You should be able to determine the packages that were uninstalled and reinstall them.

@GeraldSchneider Thanks, but it didn't work. I had just installed x-ubuntu and then uninstalled it. sudo apt-get install gdm xubuntu-desktop and sudo apt remove xubuntu-desktop

I had to reinstall Ubuntu to fix this problem.
